# Calling a thread inside a thread gives me errors, works fine if I just call the function

Tags: c++, multithreading, mingw, codeblocks

Can you call a thread from inside another thread? I have a C++ program that interacts with a C library which communicates with a serial port. I can call the function and it compiles, but when I try to call it using a thread, it throws out a couple of errors.
I have college experience with MATLAB and Arduino, and have hacked a few things together in C++, but am still pretty new to C++. This is my first time trying anything with threading.
I'll be happy to provide whatever other information is needed.

This compiles just fine:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char readVals[4096];
    CheckCOMPort(readVals); //This is the function call in question
    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char readVals[4096];
    std::thread scanCOMPort(CheckCOMPort(readVals)); //This is the thread function call in question
    stop_flag = true;
    scanCOMPort.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in ComPortReadWrite (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\...\functional||In instantiation of 'struct std::_Bind_simple<bool()>':|
C:\...\thread|142|required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = bool; _Args = {}]'|
C:\...\COMPort.cpp|122|required from here|
C:\...\functional|1505|error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<bool()>'|
C:\...\functional|1526|error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<bool()>'|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to actually call `CheckCOMPort()` in the main thread and then pass its return value to `std::thread`.  That is not what you want.  You need to pass `CheckCOMPort()` itself to `std::thread` instead, along with the parameter(s) that you want the thread to pass to `CheckCOMPort()` when the thread calls it.

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char readVals[4096];
    std::thread scanCOMPort(CheckCOMPort, readVals);
    stop_flag = true;
    scanCOMPort.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the function pointer, then its parameters separated by comma.

```
std::thread scanCOMPort(CheckCOMPort, readVals);
```

you can read more on how it works at the internet.